# If statement in Bash creates weird 0 file

Tags: bash, if-statement

When I run the following command:

```
if [ $(vboxmanage list vms | grep -c "all-in-one-1.2.7-wizard") > 0 ]; then
    echo 'yes'
else 
    echo 'no'
fi
```

a `0` file is created in the current directory:

```
$ ll
...
-rw-rw-r--  1 abc abc     0 Nov 19 17:33 0
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not doing an integer comparison, but redirecting the output of the command `$()` into `0`, so a file with `0` name is created.

Also, the current "resolution" of the if-condition is based on the result of the execution of the condition. If it is successful, then it executes the condition.

Instead, use `-gt` (`g`reater `t`han):

```
if [ $(vboxmanage list vms | grep -c "all-in-one-1.2.7-wizard") -gt 0 ]; then
                                                                 ^^
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

You can make sure this is the behaviour by doing `>7` or whatever and see a file `7` (or whatever) gets created.

When would the `else` condition be executed? If you couldn't redirect:

```
$ [ $(ls /root) > 3 ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
ls: cannot open directory /root: Permission denied
no
```

See [Numeric comparison](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Numeric_comparison) for the list of all the possible integer comparisons.

Comment: or simply use `grep -q`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out! Also, I think it is `-gt` to reflect my comparison.